# Bulk image resizer with definable sizes and methods

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for some software that will allow me to take a folder of images and resize each image to a variety of different sizes. I'd like to be able to

- bulk resize images
- define the exact sizes for the resizing - via an xml file, a ini file, or some other text file method. I'd like the final sizes to be calculated (determined using automated means), so having to then put those sizes in a ui in the software would be worse-case scenario. I'd like to apply these settings to a large amount of images, so wouldn't want to define them for each image that I want to resize.
- have a variety of resizing methods for each size - e.g. crop around centre, crop around user-defined point, resize, including seam carving, content aware resizing etc
- to run on Windows 8 or Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I always used http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php for that. Documentation may be a bit confusing, but it can do a lot!

Comment: It doesn't meet my specs at all though?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. Use wildcards for mass resize, shell scripts for size configuration via text, there are so many methods for resizing it's confusing, and it works for linux. I'd give you the real working examples, but I don't remember console commands at all. To be honest, I think making your own tool is simplier than learning ImageMagick.

Comment: @BorbonHause Could you add the details from that comment to your answer? Right now it's low-quality. Thanks :)